# Playing mp3 data compressed by lame mp3 with JLayer and Audiotrack in android

Tags: android, audio, lame, audiotrack, jlayer

I have followed this [example](https://github.com/yhirano/SimpleLameLibForAndroid) to convert raw audio data coming from AudioRecord to mp3, and it happened successfully, if I store this data in a file the mp3 file and play with music player then it is audible.

Now my question is instead of storing mp3 data to a file i need to play it with AudioTrack, the data is coming from the Red5 media server as live stream, but the problem is AudioTrack can only play PCM data, so i can only hear noise from my data.

Now i am using [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) to my require task.

My code is as follows.

```
int readresult = recorder.read(audioData, 0, recorderBufSize);
int encResult = SimpleLame.encode(audioData,audioData, readresult, mp3buffer);
```

and this mp3buffer data is sent to other user by Red5 stream.

data received at other user is in form of stream, so for playing it the code is

```
    Bitstream bitstream = new Bitstream(data.read());
    Decoder decoder = new Decoder();
    Header frameHeader = bitstream.readFrame();
    SampleBuffer output = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream);
    short[] pcm = output.getBuffer();
    player.write(pcm, 0, pcm.length);
```

But my code freezes at bitstream.readFrame after 2-3 seconds, also no sound is produced before that.

Any guess what will be the problem? Any suggestion is appreciated.

**Note**: I don't need to store the mp3 data, so i cant use MediaPlayer, as it requires a file or filedescriptor.

Comment: `AudioRecord` gives you PCM data, and `AudioTrack` plays PCM data. So if you don't need to save the audio to a file, why are you mp3 encoding it? (even if you need to mp3 encode it for some reason, you can still take the same PCM data that you're feeding to the encoder and write it to the `AudioTrack`).

Comment: The reason is i need to stream the data over net, and plain pcm data causes lots of data to send(4K per sample) and mp3 requires(max 500 bytes), so sender sends mp3 data and receiver receives this mp3 data continuously as a stream.

Comment: Ok, but the last part of my previous comment should still apply.

Answer (score 0):

just a tip, but try to

```
output.close();
bitstream.closeFrame();
```

after yours write code. I'm processing MP3 same as you do, but I'm closing buffers after usage and I have no problem.
Second tip - do it in Thread or any other Background process. As you mentioned these deaf 2 seconds, media player may wait until you process whole stream because you are loading it in same thread.
Try both tips (and you should anyway). In first, problem could be in internal buffers; In second you probably fulfill Media's input buffer and you locked app (same thread, full buffer cannot receive your input and code to play it and release same buffer is not invoked because writing locks it...)
Also, if you don't doing it now, check for 'frameHeader == null' due to file end.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the frames like this:

```
While (frameHeader = bitstream.readFrame()){
    SampleBuffer output = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream);
    short[] pcm = output.getBuffer();
    player.write(pcm, 0, pcm.length);
    bitstream.close();
}
```

And make sure you are not running them on main thread.(This is probably the reason of freezing.)